# how to configure activiti 5.21.0 with webconfigurer.class

Tags: activiti, bpmn

my previous version of activiti is 5.11 and now i'm trying to update it to 5.21.0. in previous configuration restlet servlet is used. Now I'm trying to configure it by webconfigurer.class. I have injected webconfigurer listener in web.xml. but it throwing an error.

web.xml entry

```
<listener><listener-class>org.activiti.rest.servlet.WebConfigurer</listener-class></listener>
```

error:

```
SEVERE: Exception sending context initialized event to listener instance of class org.activiti.rest.servlet.WebConfigurer
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'demoDataConfiguration': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.AbstractMethodError: org.activiti.bpmn.converter.child.BaseChildElementParser.parseChildElement(Ljavax/xml/stream/XMLStreamReader;Lorg/activiti/bpmn/model/BaseElement;Lorg/activiti/bpmn/model/BpmnModel;)V
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InitDestroyAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessBeforeInitialization(InitDestroyAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:136)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyBeanPostProcessorsBeforeInitialization(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:408)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1558)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:539)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:476)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:303)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:299)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:194)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:755)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:757)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:480)
    at org.activiti.rest.servlet.WebConfigurer.contextInitialized(WebConfigurer.java:45)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:4961)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5455)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:901)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:877)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:634)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory(HostConfig.java:1230)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig$DeployDirectory.run(HostConfig.java:1876)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:471)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:262)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.lang.AbstractMethodError: org.activiti.bpmn.converter.child.BaseChildElementParser.parseChildElement(Ljavax/xml/stream/XMLStreamReader;Lorg/activiti/bpmn/model/BaseElement;Lorg/activiti/bpmn/model/BpmnModel;)V
    at org.activiti.bpmn.converter.util.BpmnXMLUtil.parseChildElements(BpmnXMLUtil.java:126)
    at org.activiti.bpmn.converter.BaseBpmnXMLConverter.parseChildElements(BaseBpmnXMLConverter.java:253)
    at org.activiti.bpmn.converter.BaseBpmnXMLConverter.parseChildElements(BaseBpmnXMLConverter.java:243)
    at org.activiti.bpmn.converter.StartEventXMLConverter.convertXMLToElement(StartEventXMLConverter.java:55)
    at org.activiti.bpmn.converter.BaseBpmnXMLConverter.convertToBpmnModel(BaseBpmnXMLConverter.java:91)
    at org.activiti.bpmn.converter.BpmnXMLConverter.convertToBpmnModel(BpmnXMLConverter.java:426)
    at org.activiti.bpmn.converter.BpmnXMLConverter.convertToBpmnModel(BpmnXMLConverter.java:284)
    at org.activiti.engine.impl.bpmn.parser.BpmnParse.execute(BpmnParse.java:187)
    at org.activiti.engine.impl.bpmn.deployer.BpmnDeployer.deploy(BpmnDeployer.java:136)
    at org.activiti.engine.impl.persistence.deploy.DeploymentManager.deploy(DeploymentManager.java:58)
    at org.activiti.engine.impl.cmd.DeployCmd.execute(DeployCmd.java:106)
```

Comment: Can you post a bit more about your setup? Did you include activiti-rest as a dependency? This is what we do in the Activiti web app project too, and then indeed add the listener to web.xml: https://github.com/Activiti/Activiti/blob/master/modules/activiti-webapp-rest2/src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/web.xml#L21

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure that all Activiti dependencies use the same version? From this error message I would expect that activiti-bpmn-model or activiti-bpmn-converter has a different version.